# 'LeafletProvider' is not exported from 'react-leaflet'

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I had this error,

```
Attempted import error: 'LeafletProvider' is not exported from 'react-leaflet'.
```

when I tried to import LeafletProvider to one of my component file as follows:

```
import { withLeaflet, MapControl, LeafletProvider } from "react-leaflet";
```

I believe I have installed the latest version of react-leaflet (v.3.2.2) and have read the documentation as much as I could but I didn't see LeafletProvider in it.

Hope someone could help me fathom what to do with this. Basically, I just want to be able to change between two or more leaflet map tilelayers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the Provider has to be imported as such:

```
import { LeafletContext } from '@react-leaflet/core';
```

and used as :

```
<LeafletContext.Provider>
```

according to this page of the documentation:

https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/core-api/#leafletprovider

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Ivo. Anyways, I still got this error: `Attempted import error: 'LeafletContext' is not exported from 'react-leaflet'.`

Comment: I think this worked tho: `import { LeafletContext } from "@react-leaflet/core";`

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation in @Ivo's answer, here's what I did:

First install:

```
npm install @react-leaflet/core
```

Then import it like this:

```
import { LeafletContext } from "@react-leaflet/core"
```

And then use as:

```
<LeafletContext.Provider>
    // enter code here
</LeafletContext.Provider>
```